# when temporary value (smart pointer) used for computation is deleted (get of its scope)?

Tags: c++

in the following program:

```
unique_ptr<char, deleter> alloc() { ... } ;

printf("%s", static_cast<char*> (alloc().get()));
```

would be the pointer returned by `get()` still valid, or it get deleted before?
please help me to understand when the unique pointer going to be deleted.

Comment: "Gets out of scope" what does it literally mean?

Comment: Temporary are destroyed at end of the global expression (at `;`). So it is safe. (but the casting is suspicious and probably wrong.)

Comment: I've provided an ansear, but to get a better one you need provide [mcve].

Comment: The "following program" is certainly not a __program__...

Answer (score 0):

This code sample is a code smell and most probably it crashes for reasons different then OP suspects.

`unique_ptr<char, deleter>` implies single `char` value.
On other head `printf("%s",` suggest this suppose to be an array of `char`.

Most probably it crashes not because `alloc().get()` is used, but because it is incorrectly created and/or declared.
I'm betting `printf` receives pointer to not null terminated c-string.

To properly fix this full context is needed.